# How can I "transpose" the data in this way (see the image)?

Tags: r, data-manipulation, transpose

I've already asked a similar question last week, but I found out that I need also the ID column and I'm not able to add multiple columns in the code that the person suggested me, so I need to ask it again.

I need to transpose the data from the left table to the right table ([image: You can see the image here]).

```
     data <- data.frame(
+   stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
+   ID = c(15262L,17382L,14892L,15262L,17382,14892L),
+   TEST = c("Pre", "Pre","Pre", "Post", "Post","Post"),
+   Q1 = c(2L, 5L,3L,3L,2L,4L),
+   Q2 = c(3L,4L,5L,3L,4L,5L),
+   Q3 = c(4L,3L,3L,2L,2L,1L))
>   
> data
     ID TEST Q1 Q2 Q3
1 15262  Pre  2  3  4
2 17382  Pre  5  4  3
3 14892  Pre  3  5  3
4 15262 Post  3  3  2
5 17382 Post  2  4  2
6 14892 Post  4  5  1
```

the code suggested by the person was:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Test) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Test, values_from = value) %>% 
  unnest()
```

I tried to:

```
final_data<- data %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols= starts_with('Q')) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Test, values_from = value) %>% 
  unnest()
```

and

```
final_data2<- data %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Test,-ID) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Test, values_from = value) %>% 
  unnest()
```

and other combinations that I don't remember, but I continue to have some warning or error messages.

ID and Q1,Q2 etc are Double type and Test as Character,

Can someone help me??

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please don't add data as images, but instead as reproducible code. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for some tips on how to do that

Comment: The image that you posted doesn't use any of the data except for the `ID` column. I'm assuming the following does *not* solve your problem? `tidyr::crossing(ID = data$ID, Questions = paste0('Q', 1 : 3))`

Comment: Hi, Thank you Konrad for you fast reply. This is just an example that I created (I can't publish the real data). The ID are just some random numbers (I could also write "1", "2" etc, but I didn't want that people think that are just crescent number) and in the real database I have more than 45 questions with names like Q1, Q1_1, Q#1 etc. I just need a formula to change the format of the table

Comment: You are on a right track, but there is no need for unnest. We need to reshape twice, wide-to-long then long-to-wide.

Comment: We dont need you to publish the real data, just reproducible data. You could easily turn what you have in the image into code (like the answer did for you)

Comment: ID TEST     Q1    Q2    Q3
  <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 15262 Pre       2     3     4
2 17382 Pre       5     4     3
3 14892 Pre       3     5     3
4 15262 Post      3     3     2
5 17382 Post      2     4     2
6 14892 Post      4     5     1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to first convert `Q1-Q3` into long format using `pivot_longer()` and then reshape to wide format taking `TEST` as target. And finally relocate the column names using `select()`:

```
library(reshape2)
library(tidyverse)

df %>% pivot_longer(cols = contains("Q"), names_to = "Questions") %>% 
            dcast(ID + Questions  ~ TEST) %>% 
            select(ID, Questions, Pre, Post)

     ID Questions Pre Post
1 14892        Q1   3    4
2 14892        Q2   5    5
3 14892        Q3   3    1
4 15262        Q1   2    3
5 15262        Q2   3    3
6 15262        Q3   4    2
7 17382        Q1   5    2
8 17382        Q2   4    4
9 17382        Q3   3    2
```

Alternatively, we could first use `pivot_longer()` taking `Q1-Q3` as targets and then use `pivot_wider()` taking `TEST` as target column to convert to wide format:

```
df %>% pivot_longer(cols = contains("Q"), names_to = "Questions") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "TEST",values_from = "value") 

     ID Questions   Pre  Post
  <int> <chr>     <int> <int>
1 15262 Q1            2     3
2 15262 Q2            3     3
3 15262 Q3            4     2
4 17382 Q1            5     2
5 17382 Q2            4     4
6 17382 Q3            3     2
7 14892 Q1            3     4
8 14892 Q2            5     5
9 14892 Q3            3     1
```

**The data**

```
df <- read.table(text = "ID TEST    Q1  Q2  Q3
15262   Pre 2   3   4
17382   Pre 5   4   3
14892   Pre 3   5   3
15262   Post    3   3   2
17382   Post    2   4   2
14892   Post    4   5   1
",header=T, check.names=F)
```

Answer (score 3):

```r
df <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  ID = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L),
  TEST = c("Pre", "Pre", "Post", "Post"),
  Q1 = c(6L, 1L, 9L, 9L),
  Q2 = c(8L, 2L, 5L, 1L),
  Q3 = c(9L, 2L, 9L, 9L)
)

library(tidyverse)

df
#>   ID TEST Q1 Q2 Q3
#> 1  1  Pre  6  8  9
#> 2  2  Pre  1  2  2
#> 3  1 Post  9  5  9
#> 4  2 Post  9  1  9

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(ID, TEST), names_to = "Q") %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(ID, Q), names_from = TEST, values_from = value)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#>      ID Q       Pre  Post
#>   <int> <chr> <int> <int>
#> 1     1 Q1        6     9
#> 2     1 Q2        8     5
#> 3     1 Q3        9     9
#> 4     2 Q1        1     9
#> 5     2 Q2        2     1
#> 6     2 Q3        2     9
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>